# How to launch Windows' RegEdit with certain path?

Tags: command-line, regedit

How do I launch Windows' [RegEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Registry_editors) with certain path located, like "`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0`", so I don't have to do the clicking?

What's the command line argument to do this? Or is there a place to find the explanation of RegEdit's switches?

Comment: As Chris mentions, [RegJump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963880.aspx) will do the trick. Also, if you find yourself jumping back and forth between several different paths, don't forget that you can set "Favorites" in Regedit. It's quite convenient, and you won't need a separate desktop icon for each one (as you might with RegJump).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a program called [RegJump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963880.aspx), by Mark Russinovich, that does just what you want. It'll launch regedit and move it to the key you want from the command line.

RegJump uses (or at least used to) use the same regedit window on each invoke, so if you want multiple regedit sessions open, you'll still have to do things the old fashioned way for all but the one RegJump has adopted. A minor caveat, but one to keep note of, anyway.

Comment: As Matt Dillard pointed out in another answer here, there's also Favorites in regedit, so you can quickly jump to different keys of your choice within regedit itself.

Comment: For Windows Vista/7/8 users: you might want to install [`elevate`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx), add it to your `PATH` and then issue `elevate regjump <path>` if you plan to use it from your command line: http://superuser.com/a/42647/97570

Comment: If you don't want to install RegJump, try @byron-persino's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12516008/4270771) instead.  It's more light-weight and does not require any third-party software.

Answer (score 36):

Use the following batch file (add to `filename.bat`):

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit /v LastKey /t REG_SZ /d Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion\Config /f
START regedit
```

to replace:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion\Config
```

with your registry path.

Comment: Best answer. Remembering that you must launch `cmd` with admin privileges to make second command function, or you can add `&` between the two commands and execute.

Comment: i think this answer should be set as the correct one as it dont need any software to be downloaded.

Comment: To have a script you can run, drop this in a .bat file:

@echo off

set /p regPath="Open regedit at path: "

REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit /v LastKey /t REG_SZ /d "%regPath%" /f

START regedit

Comment: @MattMiller Thanks for the script. if anyone is curious, the newlines are meant to be at "@echo", "set", "REG ADD" and "START". This works for me, but RegJump did not.

Comment: Brilliant! Best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From http://windowsxp.mvps.org/jumpreg.htm (I have not tried any of these):

When you start Regedit, it automatically opens the last key that was viewed. (Registry Editor in Windows XP saves the last viewed registry key in a separate location). If you wish to jump to a particular registry key directly without navigating the paths manually, you may use any of these methods / tools.

**Option 1**
Using a VBScript:  Copy these lines to a Notepad document as save as registry.vbs

```
'Launches Registry Editor with the chosen branch open automatically
'Author  : Ramesh Srinivasan
'Website: http://windowsxp.mvps.org

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim MyKey
MyKey = Inputbox("Type the Registry path")
MyKey = "My Computer\" & MyKey
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Lastkey",MyKey,"REG_SZ"
WshShell.Run "regedit", 1,True
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Double-click Registry.vbs and then type the full registry path which you want to open.

Example: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.MP3`

Limitation: The above method does not help if Regedit is already open.

Note: For Windows 7, you need to replace the line `MyKey = "My Computer\" & MyKey` with `MyKey = "Computer\" & MyKey` (remove the string `My`). For a German Windows XP the string `"My Computer\"` must be replaced by `"Arbeitsplatz\"`.

**Option 2**
Regjump from Sysinternals.com

This little command-line applet takes a registry path and makes Regedit open to that path. It accepts root keys in standard (e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) and abbreviated form (e.g. HKLM).

Usage: regjump [path]

Example: `C:\Regjump HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp3`

**Option 3**
12Ghosts JumpReg from 12ghosts.com

Jump to registry keys from a tray icon! This is a surprisingly useful tool. You can manage and directly jump to frequently accessed registry keys. Unlimited list size, jump to keys and values, get current key with one click, jump to key in clipboard, jump to same in key in HKCU or HKLM. Manage and sort keys with comments in an easy-to-use tray icon menu. Create shortcuts for registry keys.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one more batch file solution with several enhancements in comparison to the other batch solutions posted here.

It sets also string value `LastKey` updated by *Regedit* itself on every exit to show after start the same key as on last exit.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "RootName=Computer"
set "RegKey=%~1"
if defined RegKey goto PrepareKey

echo/
echo Please enter the path of the registry key to open.
echo/
set "RegKey="
set /P "RegKey=Key path: "

rem Exit batch file without starting Regedit if nothing entered by user.
if not defined RegKey goto EndBatch

:PrepareKey
rem Remove double quotes and square brackets from entered key path.
set "RegKey=%RegKey:"=%"
if not defined RegKey goto EndBatch
set "RegKey=%RegKey:[=%"
if not defined RegKey goto EndBatch
set "RegKey=%RegKey:]=%"
if not defined RegKey goto EndBatch

rem Replace hive name abbreviation by appropriate long name.
set "Abbreviation=%RegKey:~0,4%"
if /I "%Abbreviation%" == "HKCC" set "RegKey=HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG%RegKey:~4%" & goto GetRootName
if /I "%Abbreviation%" == "HKCR" set "RegKey=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT%RegKey:~4%" & goto GetRootName
if /I "%Abbreviation%" == "HKCU" set "RegKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER%RegKey:~4%" & goto GetRootName
if /I "%Abbreviation%" == "HKLM" set "RegKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%RegKey:~4%" & goto GetRootName
if /I "%RegKey:~0,3%" == "HKU" set "RegKey=HKEY_USERS%RegKey:~3%"

:GetRootName
rem Try to determine automatically name of registry root.
if not exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe (set "RegEXE=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe") else set "RegEXE=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%K in ('%RegEXE% QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v "LastKey"') do if /I "%%K" == "LastKey" for /F "delims=\" %%N in ("%%M") do set "RootName=%%N"

rem Is Regedit already running?
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq regedit.exe" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L regedit.exe >nul || goto SetRegPath

echo/
echo Regedit is already running. Path can be set only when Regedit is not running.
echo/
set "UserChoice=N"
set /P "UserChoice=Terminate Regedit (y/N): "
if /I "%UserChoice:"=%" == "y" %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM regedit.exe >nul 2>nul & goto SetRegPath
echo Switch to running instance of Regedit without setting entered path.
goto StartRegedit

:SetRegPath
rem Add this key as last key to registry for Regedit.
%RegEXE% ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v "LastKey" /d "%RootName%\%RegKey%" /f >nul 2>nul

:StartRegedit
if not exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe (start %SystemRoot%\regedit.exe) else %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe /D /C start %SystemRoot%\regedit.exe

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The enhancements are:

1. Registry path can be passed also as command line parameter to the batch script.
2. Registry path can be entered or pasted with or without surrounding double quotes.
3. Registry path can be entered or pasted or passed as parameter with or without surrounding square brackets.
4. Registry path can be entered or pasted or passed as parameter also with an abbreviated hive name (`HKCC`, `HKCU`, `HKCR`, `HKLM`, `HKU`).
5. Batch script checks for already running *Regedit* as registry key is not shown when starting *Regedit* while *Regedit* is already running. The batch user is asked if running instance should be terminated to restart it for showing entered registry path. If the batch user chooses not to terminate all instances of *Regedit*, *Regedit* is started without setting entered path resulting (usually) in just getting *Regedit* window to foreground.
6. The batch file tries to automatically get name of registry root which is on English Windows XP **My Computer**, on German Windows XP, **Arbeitsplatz**, and on Windows 7 and newer Windows just **Computer**. This could fail if the value `LastKey` of *Regedit* is missing or empty in registry. Please set the right root name in third line of the batch code for this case.
7. The batch file runs on 64-bit Windows always *Regedit* in 64-bit execution environment even on batch file being processed by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows which is important for [registry keys affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

Comment: I performed command with "Computer" as root although my registry root was "Computador" (pt-br), and it worked well, regardless of the root name...

Comment: @kokbira Nice to know that this batch file works also for Brazil and that it could find out `Computador` as root name by itself using the code under label `GetRootName` and explained briefly in point 6.

Answer (score 4):

I'd also like to note that you can view and edit the registry from within PowerShell. Launch it, and use set-location to open the registry location of your choice. The short name of an HKEY is used like a drive letter in the file system (so to go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software, you'd say: set-location hklm:\Software).

More details about managing the registry in PowerShell can be found by typing get-help Registry at the PowerShell command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this C# solution might help:

By making use of an earlier suggestion, we can trick RegEdit into opening the key we want even though we can't pass the key as a parameter.

In this example, a menu option of "Registry Settings" opens RegEdit to the node for the program that called it.

Program's form:

```
    private void registrySettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = string.Format(@"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\{0}\{1}\",
                                    Application.CompanyName, Application.ProductName);

        MyCommonFunctions.Registry.OpenToKey(path);

    }
```

MyCommonFunctions.Registry

```
    /// <summary>Opens RegEdit to the provided key
    /// <para><example>@"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompanyName\MyProgramName\"</example></para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FullKeyPath"></param>
    public static void OpenToKey(string FullKeyPath)
    {
        RegistryKey rKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit", true);
        rKey.SetValue("LastKey",FullKeyPath);

        Process.Start("regedit.exe");
    }
```

Of course, you could put it all in one method of the form, but I like reusablity.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the below text and save it as a batch file and run

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P "showkey=Please enter the path of the registry key: "
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v "LastKey" /d "%showkey%" /f
start "" regedit
```

Input the path of the registry key you wish to open when the batch file prompts for it, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Regedit opens to the key defined in that value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple PowerShell function based off of this answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516008/1179573

```
function jumpReg ($registryPath)
{
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" `
                     -Name "LastKey" `
                     -Value $registryPath `
                     -PropertyType String `
                     -Force

    regedit
}

jumpReg ("Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run") | Out-Null
```

The answer above doesn't actually explain very well what it does. When you close RegEdit, it saves your last known position in `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit`, so this merely replaces the last known position with where you want to jump, then opens it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a BAT file using clipboard.exe and regjump.exe
to jump to the key in the clipboard:

```
clipboard.exe > "%~dp0clipdata.txt"
set /p clipdata=input < "%~dp0clipdata.txt"
regjump.exe %clipdata%
```

( %~dp0 means "the path to the BAT file" )

Comment: 'clipboard' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [lionkingrafiki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697203/1683264), here's a more robust solution that will accept a reg key path as an argument and will automatically translate HKLM to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or similar as needed.  If no argument, the script checks the clipboard using the `htmlfile` COM object invoked by a [JScript hybrid chimera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747067/1683264).  The copied data will be split and tokenized, so it doesn't matter if it's not trimmed or even among an entire paragraph of copied dirt.  And finally, the key's existence is verified before `LastKey` is modified.  Key paths containing spaces must be within double quotes.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
:: regjump.bat
@echo off & setlocal & goto main

:usage
echo Usage:
echo   * %~nx0 regkey
echo   * %~nx0 with no args will search the clipboard for a reg key
goto :EOF

:main
rem // ensure variables are unset
for %%I in (hive query regpath) do set "%%I="

rem // if argument, try navigating to argument.  Else find key in clipboard.
if not "%~1"=="" (set "query=%~1") else (
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do (
        set "query=%%~I"
    )
)

if not defined query (
    echo No registry key was found in the clipboard.
    goto usage
)

rem // convert HKLM to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, etc. while checking key exists
for /f "delims=\" %%I in ('reg query "%query%" 2^>NUL') do (
    set "hive=%%~I" & goto next
)

:next
if not defined hive (
    echo %query% not found in the registry
    goto usage
)

rem // normalize query, expanding HKLM, HKCU, etc.
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%I in ("%query%") do set "regpath=%hive%\%%~J"
if "%regpath:~-1%"=="\" set "regpath=%regpath:~0,-1%"

rem // https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697203/1683264
>NUL 2>NUL (
    REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit"^
        /v "LastKey" /d "%regpath%" /f
)

echo %regpath%

start "" regedit
goto :EOF

@end // begin JScript hybrid chimera
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747067/1683264
var clip = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile').parentWindow.clipboardData.getData('text');

clip.replace(/"[^"]+"|\S+/g, function($0) {
    if (/^\"?(HK[CLU]|HKEY_)/i.test($0)) {
        WSH.Echo($0);
        WSH.Quit(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the main goal is just to avoid "the clicking", then in Windows 10 you can just type or paste the destination path into RegEdit's address bar and hit enter.

[image: RegEdit address bar]

The `Computer\` prefix here is added automatically. It will also work if you simply type or paste a path starting with e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...`.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell way:

```
Function Jump-Registry([string]$registryPath) {
  $key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit", $true)

  if ((Test-Path ('registry::' + $registryPath) -PathType Container -ea si) -and ![System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($key)) 
  {
    $key.SetValue("LastKey", $registryPath, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
    $key.Close()
    [void]([System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("regedit.exe"))
  } else {
    Write-Error "[ $registryPath ]   may not exist. Please check the path and try again"
  }
}
```

```
Jump-Registry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
```

Or:

```
Jump-Registry "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems horribly out of date, but *[Registration Info Editor (REGEDIT) Command-Line Switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82821)* claims that it *doesn't* support this.

Comment: That's a whole different regedit... What we call regedit now is not the same as the Win3.x regedit. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141377/en-us

Answer (score 0):

You can make it appear like regedit does this behaviour by creating a batch file (from the submissions already given) but call it regedit.bat and put it in the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder. (you may want it to skip editting the lastkey in the registry if no command line args are given, so "regedit" on its own works as regedit always did) Then "regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0" will do what you want.

This uses the fact that the order in PATH is usually C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem; etc

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell code:

```
# key you want to open
$regKey = "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Policies\"
# set starting location for regedit
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" "LastKey" $regKey
# open regedit (-m allows multiple regedit windows)
regedit.exe -m
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer overall, as it's quick, simple and there's no need to install any program.
By **Byron Persino**, improved by **Matt Miller**. (Many thanks to both of them!)

*I'm rewording more correctly and clearly to help other readers like me, as I had a lot of trouble getting it clear and make it working.*

Make a .bat file, eg. 'GoToRegEditPath.bat' , write the following code inside and save it:

CODE:

```
@echo off
set /p regPath="Open regedit at path: " 
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit /v LastKey /t REG_SZ /d "%regPath%" /f
START regedit
exit
:: source: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137182/how-to-launch-windows-regedit-with-certain-path?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top
```

Maybe this .bat use must "**Run as Administrator**"
*To use it, Just run it and paste (R-Click) in it the copied RegEdit Path.*

*Tip: if R-click does not work inside command prompt:

R-click on title bar > Properties > check both under "Edit Options"*