# How to open regedit with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm looking for way to open registry editor and show some specific key or value. For example, if I pass `"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Skype\\Installer"` I want to get such a result:[image]

All suggestions except `system()` calls are welcome.

Comment: Why no `system()` calls?  You're essentially asking to launch an external program here, don't see why you'd not use `system()` or a related fork/exec type thing to do so.

Comment: What is wrong with `system()`?  That is simple shortcut for a bunch of setup to calling CreateProcess, etc.

Comment: I find that link full of mostly bogus information and irrelevant to what you are trying to do.  You want to actually run REGEDIT.EXE.  Whether you do it via `system` or by creating a separate process and launching it, you will have the same result and restrictions etc.  It's one thing to avoid using `system` to run a utility that you can query an API for to get information, it's another thing entirely when your *expressed goal* is to run the program in question.

Comment: system() calls are potentially harmful because they *create processes*. Opening regedit requires creating a process. If you want to create a process, then creating a process is, well, part of the task.

Comment: BTW. What is wrong with my question? I'm asking this all downvoters

Comment: @Ben I agree what in `system()` way and in another way another process will be launched, but while calling `system()` you make hole in OS. Because it is probably the easiest part of reverse engineering, is to change strings values. I have seen such a malware which rewrite some purely designed software.

Comment: well, you're gonna have to put "regedit.exe" somewhere, so that the computer knows you want to run regedit. And then someone can change it to "deleteeverythingandsendmybankaccountdetailstocriminals.exe", I guess. It is literally impossible to write a program which does not perform differently if its data is maliciously changed.

Comment: @Ben Well you are half right. Yes it is possible to change string values in both ways. But during lets say `ShellExecute()` is much more difficult to make run another stuff because during `system()` call you set all parameters in one place it means what during non `system()` call hacker needs to amass request and it is **much much more difficult**. I know it is impossible to make 100% safe software but we need to try.

Comment: CreateProcess then one of these; [How to launch windows regedit with certain path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137182/how-to-launch-windows-regedit-with-certain-path)

Comment: Why don't you use the Windows API to find and change registry values?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I do not need to change values. I need to open regedit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is alomost dublicate. I have looked through that and answers was about listing values, not about opening regedit. What is more that question is about cmd. I posted my function, if you do not believe, investigate that.

Comment: @user2623967: The answer I linked to does open RegEdit to the desired path, via a Registry hack that tells RegEdit what path to open to. `system()` just calls `CreateProcess()` to execute a copy of `cmd.exe` with the specified input command as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is, what I needed.

```
String GetFullHKEY (HKEY hKeyRoot)
{
    if (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE == hKeyRoot) return _T("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\");
    if (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT == hKeyRoot) return _T("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\");
    if (HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG == hKeyRoot) return _T("HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\\");
    if (HKEY_CURRENT_USER == hKeyRoot) return _T("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\");
    if (HKEY_USERS == hKeyRoot) return _T("HKEY_USERS\\");
}

bool RegistryGoTo (HKEY hKeyRoot, const String &lpctPath, String lpctValue)
{
    if (lpctPath.empty() || 0 == hKeyRoot) 
        return false;
    if( lpctValue.empty() && lpctValue.empty() == 0)
    {
        lpctValue.clear();
    }

    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shi = { 0 };
    DEVMODE dm = { 0 };

    HWND hWndRegedit = ::FindWindow (_T("RegEdit_RegEdit"), NULL);
    if (NULL == hWndRegedit)
    {
        shi.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
        shi.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS; 
        shi.lpVerb = _T("open"); 
        shi.lpFile = _T("regedit.exe"); 
        shi.nShow  = SW_SHOWNORMAL; 

        ShellExecuteEx (&shi);
        if( GetLastError() != 0 )
        {
            Sleep(200);
            ShellExecuteEx (&shi);
        }
        WaitForInputIdle (shi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        hWndRegedit = ::FindWindow (_T("RegEdit_RegEdit"), NULL);
    }

    if (NULL == hWndRegedit) return FALSE;

    SetForegroundWindow (hWndRegedit);
    ShowWindow (hWndRegedit, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    HWND hWndTreeView = FindWindowEx (hWndRegedit, NULL, _T ("SysTreeView32"), NULL);
    SetForegroundWindow (hWndTreeView);
    SetFocus (hWndTreeView);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        SendMessage (hWndTreeView, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0);
    } 

    dm.dmSize = sizeof (DEVMODE);
    EnumDisplaySettings (NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm);

    if (8 < dm.dmBitsPerPel) Sleep (100);

    // the path must start with a backslash
    String stRegPath = String (_T("\\")) + GetFullHKEY(hKeyRoot) + lpctPath;

    // open path
    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < (int) stRegPath.length (); iIndex++)
    {
        if (_T('\\') == stRegPath [iIndex])  
        {
            SendMessage (hWndTreeView, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0);

            if (8 < dm.dmBitsPerPel) 
                Sleep (100);
        } 
        else SendMessage (hWndTreeView, WM_CHAR, toupper (stRegPath [iIndex]), 0);
    } 

    SetForegroundWindow (hWndRegedit);
    SetFocus (hWndRegedit);

    if (lpctValue.length())
    {
        HWND hWndListView = FindWindowEx (hWndRegedit, NULL, _T("SysListView32"), NULL);
        SetForegroundWindow (hWndListView);
        SetFocus (hWndListView);

        Sleep (100); 

        SendMessage (hWndListView, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_HOME, 0);

        String stValue = lpctValue;

        for (String::iterator it = stValue.begin (); it != stValue.end (); ++it)
        {
            SendMessage (hWndListView, WM_CHAR, toupper (*it), 0);
        } 
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is some really elaborate code that is not actually needed.  You are doing inadequate error handling, and you are leaking the process handle that `ShellExecuteEx()` returns. You could just put the desired path in the Registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Lastkey`) and then run RegEdit and be done with it. No need to manally send keystrokes to the RegEdit window.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `system`. To use Raymond Chen's words: [It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/08/592350.aspx). Any relevant attack requires compromising the machine to the point that your `system` call is utterly irrelevant. In fact, any attacker that can change `RegEdit` can change *your* program as well, so he could just add that `system` call. (Which he won't, since it is pointless anyway)

Comment: Ok, lets say I'll use `system()` what parameters should I use?

Comment: `system("regedit")` should do it for a normally configured system.