# RegEdit open location with script

Tags: windows, vbscript

First off, I do not want to rewrite a value.

I wish to open for example the following:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\IBM\ADSM\CurrentVersion\Nodes

That is it, I've been looking at vbs scripts and seen the following:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\IBM\ADSM\CurrentVersion\Nodes\","REG_SZ"
WshShell.Run "regedit", 1,True
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

This however just opens regedit at the base directory.

Comment: I think you're missing a param of `RegWrite`. You should be passing `Name`, `Value`, `Type`. It looks like you're passing `Name`, `Type`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch windows regedit with certain path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137182/how-to-launch-windows-regedit-with-certain-path). If you want to go the VBScript route you need to write the key you want opened to a specific registry key before starting `RegEdit`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers So I cannot just open the listing?

Comment: No. Please read the answers to the question I referred you to. One of them explains en detail how starting `RegEdit` with a specific registry path works.